# Visual Studio Start Project Form Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2012

This is the first time I have had this kind of issue, and I am not really sure what I should have put as the title to this thread, because I kind of know what the issue is(I think) but I don't know a work-around.

In my project, when it is ran, I show a splashscreen which loads resources and then it breaks away to the primary editor, which is started and launched in a new thread; here is the code:

```
void EngineLoader_RunWorkerCompleted( object sender , RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
        {
            new Thread( new ThreadStart( delegate
            {
                using( _editorInstance )
                {
                    Application.Run( _editorInstance );
                }
            } ) ).Start();
            this.Dispose();
        }
```

In the above code I create the new primary thread instance, launch it, and then dispose of the splashscreen, which once had the first application thread instance. It works, except my primary editor always starts BEHIND the current Visual Studio window, even if I set the form window state to maximized or try to force a focus on it. Due to this, I have to always move my mouse down to the taskbar and click on the application Icon to force the editor to appear above the Visual Studio window. I am certain that this is happening because I am creating and launching the new form in a new thread, and somehow it is not obtaining some kind of "Current Window look at me"...thing. Here is another picture showing what I see after the splash screen goes away:

[image]

Update:

I just noticed that if I DON'T dispose of the splash screen, the new window pops up just as it should—in front/above the current visual studio window. So this code fixes it:

```
void EngineLoader_RunWorkerCompleted( object sender , RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
        {
            new Thread( new ThreadStart( delegate
            {
                using( _editorInstance )
                {
                    Application.Run( _editorInstance );
                }
            } ) ).Start();
            //this.Dispose(); // Comment it out, so that the thread is not killed.
        }
```

But the thing is, I WANT the first thread to be killed, and the splash screen along with it. It just seems that the new primary application thread is not gaining the kind of "focus" that it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting this because I did find a solution, although I feel as though it is more of an ugly hack than a solution. Instead of disposing of the splashscreen form(which kills the associated thread leaving only the new one running) we explicitly terminate the thread; this apparently works, because the new form(which is the bulk of the engine) pops up above the current visual studio window and when it is closed, the thread dies and the full running project closes(which means I did not have any lingering threads running).

Here is the current solution:

```
void EngineLoader_RunWorkerCompleted( object sender , RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
        {
            new Thread( new ThreadStart( delegate
            {
                using( _editorInstance )
                {
                    Application.Run( _editorInstance );
                }
            } ) ).Start();
            Application.Exit();// Take the thread out back behind the shed and shoot it in the head.
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between "this.Dispose()" and "Application.Exit()" in terms of swapping threads out?